# How do I output form results to a specific part of a page?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a web app that takes a user input and outputs the result to the lower part of the main page. There are two pairs of **form** tags--a main form and a secondary form. I want the output produced by the main form to show above the secondary form.

The secondary form does not output anything. It is a button that says "Show All Folders". See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tlrbk.png). I want the result where the red arrow is pointing to.

```
#!C:\Python\Python38-32\python.exe
import cgi
import os
import re

print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()

input = cgi.FieldStorage()

print("""
<head> 
 <title> Search </title>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function showHide() {
   var div = document.getElementById('hidden_div');
   if (div.style.display == 'none') {
     div.style.display = '';
   }
   else {
     div.style.display = 'none';
   }
 }
</script>

</head>
<style type="text/css"> 
 body{
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #333;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background: #BBDEFB;
 }

 h1{
  font-size: 30px;
  background: #2196F3;
  padding: 5px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 99%;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 4px rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.15);
  border-radius: 12px;
  color: #E3F2FD;
 }

 #mainForm form{
  background: #E3F2FD;
  padding: 25px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.35);
  border-radius: 5px;
 }

  #secondaryForm form{
  background: #E3F2FD;
  padding: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.35);
  border-radius: 5px;
 }

 .result_1{
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #333;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.35);
 }

  .result_2{
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #333;
  padding: 2px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-radius: 1px;
 }

 input[type=text]{
  background-color: #42A5F5;
  color: #E3F2FD;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 8px 20px 8px 12px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  height: px;
  border-radius: 8px;
 }

 input[type=submit]{
  background-color: #42A5F5;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(44, 62, 80, 0.35);
 }

 div.a {
  text-align: right;
}

</style>
""")


print("""<body>

<h1><center>SEARCH FILES</center></h1>


<div id="mainForm">
<form action="search_sample.py">
 Enter Value to Search<br>
 <input type="text" name="user_input"><br>
 <br>

 Select File Type<br>
 <input type="radio" name="operator" value="o_file" checked> O File <br>
 <input type="radio" name="operator" value="l_file"> L File <br>
 <br>

 <input type="submit" value="Submit"><br>
</form>
</div>

<div id="secondaryForm">
<form name="showfolders" onsubmit="showHide(); return false;">
<input type="submit" value="Show All Folders" name="show_folder" />
</form>
</div>

""")

# Begin Python script
my_dir = "C:/Users/xstah/OneDrive/Documents/sample_txt/"

# Get all folders  
print('<div id="hidden_div" style="display:none">')
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(my_dir):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".dat"):
            filename2 = os.path.join(root, file)
            
            filepath_split = os.path.normpath(filename2)
            path_list = filepath_split.split(os.sep)
            hostname = path_list[6]
            foldername = path_list[7]
            print('<div class="result_1">{}</div>'.format('<b>'+ hostname + '</b>'))
            print('<div class="result_2">{}</div>'.format(foldername))
        
print('</div>')
    
# User input & selection
user_input = input["user_input"].value
operation = input["operator"].value

# End Python script
    
print("</body>")
```

Comment: I'm curious. Your script almost did nothing other than printing HTML codes. Why don't you just use a HTML file instead? There is no Python logic at all.

Comment: I intentionally removed the Python codes as I didn't want to bombard the post with too many codes.

Comment: I've added some Python codes. Please let me know if more is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make div between main and secondary forms there and do innerHTML or innerText by js.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what is it that I should try? I have never used innerHTML. Thanks.

Comment: in which JS function you receive a list of folders?

Comment: I am not using a JS function. I am using Python to get a list of subdirectories in a path and then having it displayed in HTML. I have updated by post to include the Python codes, as well as, some additional HTML codes. Please take a look. Thanks.